# SystemD `Requires` fail when required unit fails for the first time

Tags: systemd, services, systemd-unit

I have created a SystemD unit to start a service, and that service requires another unit to start beforehand.

I've set the depending service with `Requires=dependant.service`, and that way when `depending.service` is automatically started during boot, it first tries to start `dependant.service`.

The problem is that if `dependant.service` starts too early, it fails to start (I'm not really sure what "too early" here means). To solve this, I've set `dependant.service` to `Restart=always`.

And that works fine - `depending.service` is enabled and starts automatically, it starts `dependant.service`, which crashes and then gets restarted and always succeeds to start on the 2nd try.

But `depending.service` have seen `dependant.service`'s first failure and its `Requires=dependant.service` causes it to fail. The log shows:

```
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for depending.
systemd[1]: Job depending.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Even though `dependant` has eventually succeeded, and both have `Restart=always`, `depending` never restarts after the initial failure of `dependant`.

I've tried various configuration of `Requires=`, `Wants=`, `BindsTo=` and `After` but didn't manage to find a combination that causes `depending` to restart after `dependant` restarts.

Comment: Remember that you need `Requires` to set the dependency and then either `After` or `Before` to set the ordering (otherwise the ordering is undefined).  Show us the `[Unit]` section of your two unit files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the root cause is that `dependant.service` is starting too soon sometimes: adding `Restart` directives is a bit of a hack. This to me indicates that it's missing a timing requirement, which is what `After` is for. Depending on the type of service, you'll need to determine what resources are needed before the service should be started.

Assuming that this is network-related, you'll want to add the following in the `[Unit]` section of `dependant.service`:

```
After=network.target
```

By doing this, you're indicating that the basic network should be available before systemd tries to start the service. Otherwise, systemd will try to start as many services in parallel as it can, which means that depending on the start order you might be starting with basically nothing initialized, which is a situation that some services can tolerate and some fail badly with.

If you want to make sure that `depending.service` always restarts with `dependant.service`, then add both a `BindsTo` and `After` to `depending.service`:

```
[Unit]
After=dependant.service
BindsTo=dependant.service
```

These behaviours are documented in the [`systemd.unit(7)` man page.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#%5BUnit%5D%20Section%20Options) I rarely have to use more than `Wants`, `Requires` and `After`, but there are more advanced options if you have services that have particularly complex start conditions.

I find it to be helpful when creating a new service (or group of services) to look in the distribution-supplied unit files to see how they are done and shamelessly copy the good parts (try `/usr/lib/systemd/system` or `/lib/systemd/system`): they often will have clues about what `After` and `Requires` requirements are useful for a particular type of service.

Comment: `BindsTo` worked for me, but I decided to rebuild my dependency in a different way (outside of SystemD, as it is mostly a "run once" situation anyway).

Answer (score 1):

For me `BindsTo` doesn't help. This is (I'm think), because `BindsTo` means that depending unit cannot run without dependant unit. But in this situation the depending process has not been started since the dependant unit failed to start first time.

But according to [systemd unit's documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=) `PartOf` propagets the event after each restarting. So this worked for me:

```
[Unit]
After=dependant.service
PartOf=dependant.service
```